# I have trouble understanding this code. Sorry for the dumb question

Tags: arrays, c, func

```
void func(int N)
{
    int i, j, arr[246913] = { 0,1 };
    for (j = 2; j < 246913 / j; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] == 1)
            continue;
        for (i = j * j; i < 246913; i += j)
            if (i % j == 0)
                arr[i] = 1;
    }

    int cnt = 0;
    for (i = N + 1; i <= N * 2; i++)
        if (arr[i] == 0)
            cnt++;
    printf("%d", cnt);
}

int main()
{
    func(7);
    func(0);
    func(4);
    func(9);
}
```

I tried to understand the code by writing the procedure of this code.
But I thought I have to understand the real meaning of this code to learn more.

I hope there is someone who can help me understand this code properly.
Also I want to know, how to understand these kinds of algorithm code problems by just seeing the code.
I hope there are any some tips for beginners like me.
Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Where did you get this code from? What information does that site or book (etc.) have about the code?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 
Hi:)
I have to take a C programming test, and that code is the questions that was taken before.

Comment: At a quick glance it seems to be about prime numbers.

Comment: This is not a fair test. It's generally hard to understand code with meaningless variable names, and no one writes real code like that. But when you see code that's looping and checking for modulus equal to 0, it means you're checking for divisors, and that's how you know it's checking for primality.

Comment: SO is not a programming school, we can't teach you how to figure this out yourself. It just comes from experience.

Comment: Repeated magic number 246913 is enough less than 1MB / sizeof(int) to not overflow your stack. This is not a good design.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`func` prints the number of primes between `N+1` and `2*N`, inclusive.  It first uses a sieve to create an array with 0 for primes and 1 for composite numbers (the entry for 0 is unused).  It then iterates from `N+1` through `2*N`, counting the 0 entries.  Finally it prints the number of 0 entries it found, i.e. the number of primes within the range.

There are a few simple optimizations it uses, but they all rely on fairly basic math so shouldn't be too hard to understand.

Comment: What question is being answered?

Comment: @nicomp I explained what the code does and how it does it.  That was the implied question.